# How to convert "media.setVolume" function to progress bar or seek bar?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I want to develop an application using phonegap and play mp3 files on it.
I learn how to develop a media app on this site
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_media_media.md.html
but i want to convert "media.setVolume" function to progress bar or seek bar, i spend a lot of my power to try convert "media.setVolume" function to progress bar or seek bar, but not work..............

My Javscript and html file

```js
var my_media = null;
     var mediaTimer = null;

   
     function pauseAudio() {
      if (my_media) {
       my_media.pause();
      }
     }
     function stopAudio() {
      if (my_media) {
       my_media.stop();
                window.location.reload();
      }
      clearInterval(mediaTimer);
      mediaTimer = null;
     }

     function setVolume(volume) {/*I want use this function to volume bar*/
                if (my_media) {
                    my_media.setVolume(volume);
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="mediaplay">
    <a id="play_btn" href="#" onclick="playAudio(getPhoneGapPath () + 'media/01.mp3');">Play</a> 
    <a id="pause_btn" href="#" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause</a> 
    <a id="stop_btn" href="#" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop</a>
<!--I want use this function to volume bar-->
    <input type="range" class="Volume_bar" value="setVolume(90)">
<!--I want use this function to volume bar-->
</div>
```

I want to convert "Volume_bar" to progress bar, the user can scroll the Volume_bar to  adjust the volume, how can do it in phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an `event listener` on the input range which will be executed when the user interacts with the control:

```
<input id="volume" type="range" class="Volume_bar">
```

The JS part:

```
document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
     const level = e.currentTarget.value;
     console.log('Current volume level: ' + level);

     setVolume(level);
});
```